# "watch" command not displaying "tree" command output with Unicode bars and dashes

Tags: command-line, bash, unix

When executing

```
watch tree .
```

I get output as follows

```
Every 2.0s: tree .                                   macbook.local: Fri Dec 20 16:23:33 2019

.
    hello.txt
    hi.txt
    hmm.c
    subdir
        hello.txt

1 directory, 4 files
```

I want it to look like regular tree command output. Like below:

```
.
├── hello.txt
├── hi.txt
├── hmm.c
└── subdir
    └── hello.txt

1 directory, 4 files
```

I know that, I can use

```
while; do; clear; tree .; sleep 2; done
```

But I want to achieve the same thing with watch command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior as all non-printable characters are stripped from the output of `watch`. And this is mentioned in `man` page of `watch`.

You can try to exec command on this way:

```
 watch "tree|cat -v"
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `LC_CTYPE=C` will probably make `tree` use plain ASCII alternatives. With `watch` the command may be:

```
watch 'LC_CTYPE=C tree .'
# or (not strictly equivalent)
LC_CTYPE=C watch tree .
```

Notes:

- The setting will affect the way non-ASCII characters in filenames are displayed.
- You may encounter a generic hint of `LC_ALL=C`. This variable overrides `LC_CTYPE`, but also `LC_COLLATE` and other `LC_*` variables. `LC_COLLATE` affects sorting in `tree`.

In my Debian I can use `--charset=C` to force ASCII drawings without affecting characters in filenames (so this is even better than the approach with `LC_CTYPE`):

```
watch tree --charset=C .
```

Although in Debian even `watch tree .` works well for me. On the other hand `watch "tree|cat -v"` from [this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1511576/432690) generates virtually unreadable output. Apparently your setup is different (`macbook.local` – macOS?). My answer is to provide hints that may be useful for users with yet another setup.